# Split MySQL value into integers

Tags: mysql, types, casting, floating-point, precision

I try to load a (biggish) csv into a table. I use:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 
'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\Uploads\\xxxx.csv'
INTO TABLE xxx
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES
  (@datetimeStr,...
```

The first value in the csv is '20000101130'.  MySQL reads @datetimeStr as 2.00001E+11 (i.e a number?!)

I need to split this number into:
Year   Day   Hour (4 characters each): i.e. 2000   0101  1130

I tried:

**SELECT @datetimeStr;**  -> Gives me '2.00001E+11' (i.e. a number)

**SELECT convert(@datetimeStr , CHAR);** -> Gives me '2.00001E+11' (i.e. also a number)???

**SELECT cast(@datetimeStr AS CHAR);** > Gives me '2.00001E+11' (i.e. also a number)???

None of these results allows me to do what I want, i.e.

**SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(@datetimeStr, CHAR), 4)** expecting '2000', but it always gives me 2.00

What am I missing?

Comment: Your attribute is eveidently defined in your schema as a float. You're trying to process it like an integer or varchar. Can you change your schema?

Comment: FYI, indent code four spaces.

Comment: I think "the first value in the csv" must be `200001011130`, not `20000101130`, for the rest of your question to make sense. Correct?

Comment: @O. Jones, yes, my bad, 200001011130 is the first value in the csv

Comment: Oh, the old Excel bug. I've lost count of how many times I've been burned by that.  Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

You have converted your character representation of timestamps into `FLOAT` numbers. That means you have lost the precision needed to extract the day of month, and the hours and minutes. That precision is gone. You need to reload your data.  `FLOAT` uses the [single-precision IEEE-754 floating point representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). It can only manage a little more than seven decimal digits of precision, so you get `2000010???` from `200001011130`.

If you had converted that precision to `DOUBLE` instead of `FLOAT` the sorts of tricks you're trying might work. `DOUBLE` uses the [double-precision representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). It handles just short of 15 decimal digits of precision, so your numbers just barely fit.

You might consider this fact and [use `STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date). This expression

```
  STR_TO_DATE('200001011130', '%Y%m%d%H%i')
```

yields a `DATETIME` value representing the time in your text string. You can then say stuff like

```
 YEAR(STR_TO_DATE('200001011130', '%Y%m%d%H%i'))
```

and

```
 TIME(STR_TO_DATE('200001011130', '%Y%m%d%H%i'))
```

to retrieve parts of that `DATETIME`.

Comment: Have universities stopped teaching people about floating-point numbers? Sigh.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  I am not sure floats in my schema are the problem, in fact the schema, doesn't come into this here.  @datetimestr is a temporary variable, where the value from the csv gets stored.  In the second part of the LOAD DATA command I want to split the 200001011130 into the 3 datetime components.

Comment: In the csv the 200001011130 is stored just like this, no quotes, just comma-delimited.  The problem is that the temporary variable @datatimestr treats 200001011130 apparently as a float (not as a long integer or string, which would help me).

Thanks for the STR_TO_DATE() tip, I didn't know this function or its use.  I can get YEAR(STR_TO_DATE('200001010000', '%Y%m%d%H%i')) to work, but not YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(@datetimeStr, '%Y%m%d%H%i'))

Comment: Is there anything that forces the LOAD DATA command to treat the csv number 200001010000 as an BIGINT or CHAR(12)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, mystery solved.

Excel was playing tricks on me.  When I reduced the original, large csv to a testable file it decided to store the datetime column as 2.00001E+11 (i.e. Excel's default "display format").  When I HexEdited the issue I inadvertently looked at the original file, which had 200001011130 in it.

So trusty old MySQL was reading 2.00001E+11 and therefore struggling to  separate dates and times.

After reformatting the column, Excel saved it correctly and all went well from there on.  (Hope it may help someone to avoid this trap.)

Thanks again for your suggestions.  The STR_TO_DATE() function is handy and possibly more efficient than string manipulations?!

And thanks for your concerns about teaching students about floats!  That's my job :-)